# Registry access - Win7 "Any CPU" vs x86

Tags: .net, windows-7, registry

We had one of our programmers make some changes that really don't make sense to anyone and i'm hoping someone can provide some insight.Unfortunately we are unable to contact him until next week but it would be nice to know this info sooner.

We have a custom application loader (built in .net) that downloads all appropriate source files and registers/unregisters dlls that are COM and runs RegASM for some assemblies. We had problems with the loader under windows 7 (x64) which he was assigned to correct.

The only thing that the individual assigned to fix this problem did was to request the loader be built as x86 rather than "Any CPU". We having trouble seeing how this could have fixed anything.

Previously we had COM registration errors and "Requested registry access is not allowed" errors when trying to create TLB files with RegASM. Does anyone have any idea how his change could have affected this at all?

Comment: Not saying it wasn't the right thing to do. Yes "Any CPU" is bad but still failing to realize how it fixed the problem we are having. Its like a x86 process would have more security than a x64 process which doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your co-workers fix was correct. Here is why:

In Windows x64 a process may be started as 32bit or 64bit process. A 64bit process can only load 64bit dlls and a 32bit process only 32bit dlls.

If your platform target (e.g. specified in the project properties) of your .NET application is set to "Any CPU", the intermediate code will be compiled to 32bit or 64bit code depending on the target platform, i.e. on a x64 system 64bit code will be generated. As a consequence, any 32-bit library such as native 32-bit COM components cannot be loaded into the64-bit process.

Comment: That is true for COM in-proc DLLs. However, a 64-bit process can load and use a 32-bit COM out-proc EXE, and vice versa. COM handles the necessary marshalling between 32-bit/64-bit for out-proc servers. If you have an in-proc DLL compiled in one bitness and need to use it in a process of another bitness, you can assign a DllSurrogate to the DLL so it runs as an out-proc server.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - TeamB: True, but this is hardly what people want. There are only few interop cases where you want your .NET code to be compiled with AnyCPU and use an out-of-process COM component when you can achieve the same by compiling to x86 and use an in-proc server. For that reason, Microsoft changed the default project templates in VS 2010 to compile to x86.